# Plural or singular verbs with singular they

Tags: singular-vs-plural, singular-they

> Q. How good is the teacher at that school?
>   A. They're a good teacher. They just sometimes **hit(s)**  their students if the students don't pay any attention to what he's saying, and then **call(s)** for parent-teacher conference.

Are we to use plural verbs with the singular they?
It seems to me that with the first one, it should be **hit** but with the second one it should **calls**.

Comment: Since the question uses "the teacher", a particular teacher is understood, who has a particular gender, so singular they in inappropriate in this particular example. The second speaker knows the teacher so should use the appropriate gendered pronoun.

Comment: @JamesK It's true for most speakers that singular *they* is inappropriate when the gender of the antecedent is known, but it's increasingly false for younger speakers.  Eventually it will probably be unremarkable.

Comment: Let's just say the answerer doesn't know the teacher himself, but has heard how they do things from someone else, who never mentioned the gender of the teacher. ._.
@JamesK